# TYPO3 ext:comments and multiple instances on the same page

Tags: typo3

I'm including the [`comments`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/comments) extension  multiple times on a page. The `StoragePid` for each element is different.  When I press the submit button from one `comments` instance, other instances submits the message as well. Is there any way to separate this?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you my extension [`toctoc_comments`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/toctoc_comments). 
It can import old *comments* and it can be used several times on a web page with same StoragePid.

The new extension is AJAX-based and has about (estimated...) 500% more functionality than *comments*. *ratings* are included, comment replies, web page previews.

Answer (score 0):

There is no extension "tx_comments". It seems that you just have posted the table name. So which extension do you exactly mean?

Comment: Hi kiri, i mean this extension:
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/comments